# fadeToggle and toggle z-index on div

Tags: jquery, toggle, z-index

I am looking to swap the z-index of my div when fading In and Out. This is what I have so far but it doesnt toggle the z-index. Any ideas?

```
   $(document).on('click', '.button', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('target');
    $('.' + id).fadeToggle("fast", "linear").toggleZindex(); 
 });

 $.fn.toggleZindex= function() {
 var $this  = $(this);
 if($this.css("display")=="block"){
    $this.css("z-index","1")
}else{
   $this.css("z-index","-1")
}
return this;
};
```

Comment: can you create this in jsfiddle ?? or post you realted html too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i assume calling the `toggleZindex()` function inside the callback function of fadeToggle() should work ..to make sure fade animation completes..

```
$(document).on('click', '.button', function() {
 var id = $(this).data('target');
 $('.' + id).fadeToggle("fast", "linear",function(){
          $(thjs).toggleZindex(); 
      });
});
```